# Making multiple POST API requests on form submission

Tags: javascript, php, html, rest, api

I'm trying to create a lead form that integrates with a lead management software(LMS) that has a REST based API.

LMS: Workflowmax - https://www.workflowmax.com/api/

Form: Basic html to be used with wordpress

From what I understand, in order to achieve what I want, there's a certain workflow:

- User submits form
- API call to use some of the form data to create "Client" object in the LMS
- Read the response to get the Client ID
- API call to use the Client ID and the rest of the form data (description) to create the "Lead" object.

It has to be this way because the "Lead" object needs a "Client" as a required field.
What I would ideally like to do is to have the user submit the form and be directed to a "Thank you" page.

I don't know how to make API calls beyond using the "action" on the form. But this doesn't get me the ability to make multiple API calls or process the response. 
How do I implement the solution?

Comment: What is the question? It's very unclear.

Comment: Apologies! I edited the post, does that make my problem clearer? I know what needs to happen, and in which order, but my coding experience is not suited to what I have to do and I'm not sure how to actually achieve the result..

Comment: You should search for and study AJAX calls.

Comment: In short, Ajax makes API calls (without refreshing the page) and gets the result, which you can use for your JavaScript and/or update html.

Comment: I'm seeing some examples at the moment, it's confusing because I don't know Ajax much. Is this something I could run on the thank you page once the form is submitted?

Comment: Ajax is JavaScript to do what you want.